# .Net 6 `JsonPropertyName` deserialisation not working

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, deserialization, system.text.json

I am trying to use `System.Text.Json` to serialize/deserialize some API response, and the `JSON` fields aren't exactly the same as the `C#` classes I am working with so for the actual names I tried using `JsonPropertyName` but it didn't seem to work like intended.
I tried going back to .Net documentation, and use one of their examples to check where I had the problem, but the deserialisation still didn't go through.
Here's the sample code I used:

```cs
var json =
    @"{""dit_date"":""2020-09-06T11:31:01.923395"",""temperature_c"":-1,""sum_mary"":""Cold""} ";
Console.WriteLine($"Input JSON: {json}");

var forecast = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Forecast>(json)!;

Console.WriteLine($"forecast.Date: {forecast.Date}");
Console.WriteLine($"forecast.TemperatureC: {forecast.TemperatureC}");
Console.WriteLine($"forecast.Summary: {forecast.Summary}");

var roundTrippedJson =
    JsonSerializer.Serialize(forecast);

Console.WriteLine($"Output JSON: {roundTrippedJson}");
```

The `Forecast` class:

```cs
public class Forecast
{
    [JsonPropertyName("dit_date")] public DateTime Date;
    [JsonPropertyName("temperature_c")] public int TemperatureC;
    [JsonPropertyName("sum_mary")] public string? Summary;
}
```

And the output I got:

```bash
Input JSON: {"dit_date":"2020-09-06T11:31:01.923395","temperature_c":-1,"sum_mary":"Cold"} 
forecast.Date: 01/01/0001 00:00:00
forecast.TemperatureC: 0
forecast.Summary: 
Output JSON: {}
```

Any idea what's wrong with this?

Comment: You'll need setters on those properties, surely?

Comment: @swatsonpicken Thank you I forgot to put them in the example, and I think my problem is elsewhere as I do have them in my other class and still getting null values. Any idea what can trigger that?

Comment: @Isu everything is working properly if you add getters setters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class members should be properties, not fields:

```
public class Forecast
{
    [JsonPropertyName("dit_date")] 
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("temperature_c")] 
    public int TemperatureC { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("sum_mary")] 
    public string? Summary { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Technically they can be fields, you just need to [include fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0#include-fields). Although using properties is much better in my opinion

Comment: @maccettura thanks for pointing that out, after spending too much time on something sometimes even the basic stuff isn't that obvious anymore. Why is that better?

Comment: Why is my link the better approach?  It's not, I was just correcting Roman on their remark of "The class members should be properties, not fields". Technically they _can_ be fields so their remark was not accurate. If you are asking for my opinion on why properties are better: It seems like the more OOP way of doing it. Properties help abstract away the details of whats happening internally